# Angular 2 How to make imports with platformBrowserDynamic in man.ts?

Tags: angular

I'm following a seemingly deprecated tutorial that has me modifying the **main.ts** file as follows:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [AuthGuard]);
```

However, my **main.ts** looks more like this.

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {enableProdMode();}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

And doing something like below does not work. I get an error `no provider for AuthGuard` when I trigger the bound event.

```
import { AuthGuard } from './whereever';    
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [AuthGuard]);
```

I am having problems even with the `AuthGuard` import correctly included. I still get a `no provider for AuthGuard` error.

Is this supposed to be working, and I simply am having errors elsewhere? My console does not specify which route the error is coming from. Let me know if my sample code should be working. If that is the case, I will update my question with more details about my specific operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the newly added `ngModule` component. It has an `@ngModule` decorator.

In your `app.module.ts`, you add all the necessary imports and define which component has to be bootstrapped:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then in `main.ts` you do the following:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Then building your app in `app.component.ts`.